# useDispatch causes 'Object(...) is not a function' error

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm doing a simple app to retrieve some messages for a dashboard, react & redux.

I have this code block:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

function Dashboard() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div>
      My dashboard!
    </div>
  )
}
```

That always returns the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" in the useReduxContext. When I comment out useDispatch, it works fine. My imports are also up to date. Other similar questions here usually showed it to be an import error, so I'm confused as to what I'm doing wrong.

Console logging useDispatch yielded this:

```
  useDispatch() {
    const store = useStore(); // @ts-ignore

    return store.dispatch;
  }
```

Comment: Is your application wrapped in a redux provider, like in this example? https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider#basic-usage